# asp.net breaking code into separate lines on the aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

What's the syntax for the aspx pages if you want to break down really long lines of code into a more readable format.

Example:

```
 <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTest" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Efficiency" ForeColor="White" Text="<img src='images/bluecell.png' /> = 66 - 100 % <br><img src='images/greencell.png' /> = 33 - 66 % <br> <img src='images/ambercell.png' /> = 0 - 33%"> </asp:Label>
```

into something like:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTest" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Efficiency"
 ForeColor="White" Text="<img src='images/bluecell.png' /> = 66 - 100 % <br><img
 src='images/greencell.png' /> = 33 - 66 % <br> <img src='images/ambercell.png' /> = 0 - 33%">
 </asp:Label>
```

Or is  it not possible to break up the value of one individual attribute?

Comment: Your markup as it is right now, is not properly formatted. `<asp:Label ... Text="..." </asp:Label>`. Did you mean to close it inline `/>`? Why would you? IIRC, the `Text` property could be the inner HTML of the label. `<asp:Label other properties>Text content</asp:Label>`...

Comment: Thats not actual code I'm using I just typed it real quick as an example. I know if can be broken down ok if used like you said, but can you break down a value of an attribute on 2 lines or more? As in the part after Attribute="this part here"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a quick play with this, and I was surprised to see that just spreading the Text attribute across multiple lines did produce valid markup (as far as I can see).

```
<asp:Label runat="server" 
           ID="lblTest" 
           CommandName="Sort" 
           CommandArgument="Efficiency" 
           ForeColor="White" 
           Text="<img src='images/bluecell.png' /> = 66 - 100 % <br>
                 <img src='images/greencell.png' /> = 33 - 66 % <br>
                 <img src='images/ambercell.png' /> = 0 - 33%" />
```

It does kind of screw with the colour formatting in VS, but when it's displayed in the browser it produces:

```
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblTest" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Efficiency" style="color:White;"><img src='images/bluecell.png' /> = 66 - 100 % <br><img src='images/greencell.png' /> = 33 - 66 % <br><img src='images/ambercell.png' /> = 0 - 33%</span>
```

So just try putting it on different lines, ignore VS trying to colour code something it doesn't understand and see what you get.

(by the way, use `<br />` instead of `<br>`)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by only pressing CTRL+k+D. Visual studio do the formatting and indenting by itself.

May it helps you.

Comment: It doesnt actually break down the long part, thats still one line. I assume its just not allowed.

Comment: Yes you are right. But the fact behind this is VS formatter cant break the text in multiple line. VS only break attributes on different line but the text in the given label is too much large and formatter cant break the text b/c it gives different meanings to text attribute. You have to break the text by yourself by adding "+ on the line end and start second line by " and also ends with "